# Passing a variable to another variable

Tags: angular

I am creating a pie chart that is generated from a variable `public pieChartData:number[] = [300, this.Goal]`. I am trying to get the correct data in my constructor with a `for` loop on an object array

```
  data = [{
    Id: 1,
    YTDGoal: 125000
  }]
```

but when passed into `pieChartData`, `this.Goal` is undefined.

How can I solve this?

I have created a [Stackblitz for this issue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ktpsp3).

Comment: I see 125000 gets write to the console.

Comment: @RedCricket It does, however it is undefined shortly after in `pieChartData`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  data = [{
    Id: 1,
    YTDGoal: 125000
  }]

  Goal;
  public pieChartLabels:string[] = ['Download Sales', 'YTD Goal'];
  public pieChartData:number[] = [300, this.Goal];
  public pieChartType:string = 'pie';
  public pieChartCustomColors = [{
    backgroundColor: ['blue', 'red']
  }]

  constructor() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
      this.Goal = this.data[i].YTDGoal
    }
    this. pieChartData = [300, this.Goal];
  }

  public chartClicked(e:any):void {
    console.log(e);
  }

  public chartHovered(e:any):void {
    console.log(e);
  }

}
```